# Combine Promises Arrays, in Only One JavaScript

Tags: javascript, nodejs-server

I am using some promises to get information, but in this case I have a principal array, my idea is:

1. For loop to each company id to get payment
2. For loop to each payment array id to get employers
3. Show in one array the results

MY CODE

```
var data =  [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    company: 'A'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    company: 'B'
                },
                {
                    id: 3,
                    company: 'C'
                }
            ]

var p1 = [];
for(var i =0; i < data.length; i++){
  p1.push(global.get_payments(data, i));
}
Promise.all(p1)
.then(response_p1 => {
    //I added the response in same structure see response_p1

    for(var i =0; i < response_p1.length; i++){
        var employers = [];
        for(var x =0; x < response_p1[i].payment.length; x++){
            employers.push(global.get_employers(response_p1[i].payment, x));
        }
        Promise.all(employers)
        .then(response_employers => {
            //I added the response into payment array
            //HOW CAN I COMBINE IN ONLY ONE ARRAY?
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
    }
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err)
})


response_p1 = [
                        {
                            id: 1,
                            company: A',
                            payment:    [
                                            {id: 4}
                                        ]
                        },
                        {
                            id: 2,
                            company: 'B',
                            payment:    [
                                            {id: 5}
                                        ]
                        },
                        {
                            id: 3,
                            company: 'C',
                            payment:    [
                                            {id: 6}
                                        ]
                        }
                    ]


response_employers = [
                        {
                            id: 4,
                            employer_list: [
                                                {id: 1, name: 'Carles'},
                                                {id: 2, name: 'Max'}
                                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                     [
                        {
                            id: 5,
                            employer_list: [
                                                {id: 3, name: 'Dania'},
                                                {id: 4, name: 'Luis'}
                                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                     [
                        {
                            id: 6,
                            employer_list: [
                                                {id: 5, name: 'Lenny'},
                                                {id: 6, name: 'Hommer'}
                                           ]
                        }
                     ]



RESULT EXPECTED [
                    {
                        id: 4,
                        employer_list: [
                                            {id: 1, name: 'Carles'},
                                            {id: 2, name: 'Max'}
                                       ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 5,
                        employer_list: [
                                            {id: 3, name: 'Dania'},
                                            {id: 4, name: 'Luis'}
                                       ]
                    },
                    {
                        id: 6,
                        employer_list: [
                                            {id: 5, name: 'Lenny'},
                                            {id: 6, name: 'Hommer'}
                                       ]
                    }
                ]
```

my problem is that I am getting 3 array and I want that response_employers should be in only one array, How can I solve that

Comment: Sounds like your problem has nothing to do with promises but is actually about turning an array of arrays into a one-dim array?

Comment: yes sir, how can I do that?

Comment: You can look up the hundreds of existing questions on stackoverflow about restructuring arrays, which is an extremely common beginner's problem that gets asked and marked as dupe on a daily basis

Comment: I don't find any question as mine

Comment: Can you check `response_employers`? It's currently invalid syntax. Also, it seems all you need is `const fixed = messy.map(arr => arr[0]);`